# Symfony3 how to use same users database with multiple projects?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.3

I have a Symfony_2.8 project with database that contains users of this app,
now i'm moving one bundle in this project to separate Symfony_3.3 project with new database ,how can i authenticate users and load them from the main project users database ?

**Note:** the two projects on the same server.

Answer (score 2):

U need to define two entity managers to connect different databases.

[Read this manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Also, u can generate User entity [from existing database](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).